# Regular Expression to find all anchor tags without rel=nofollow then add it

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, regex

Our SEO team want us to ensure that any posts that we publish in our forum, that contain links, have the rel="nofollow" attribute.

We have code in place to put `rel="nofollow"` in, if our link tools are used when posting the message, but what I need is a function that is called as we output each post, to find any instances of `<a ...>foo</a>` and replace with `<a rel="nofollow" ...>foo</a>`. Obviously I'd like to avoid blatting every anchor tag I come across with the attribute or we'll end up with tags that contain duplicate nofollow attributes.

Unfortunately, I'm not good with regular expressions and I assume this will be the best way to accomplish it?

Comment: Please don't try parsing HTML using Regex.  HTML is not a regular language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using an HTML parser such as the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) to parse, query and reqrite the HTML.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for a compelling explanation why RegEx tends to be a bad idea for parsing HTML.

Comment: I was hoping someone would link to that compelling explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

it's extremely easy client side if you're using jquery

```
$(function(){
  $("a").attr("rel","nofollow");
});
```

is all it takes

Comment: The problem here is that rel="nofollow" is usually just used by search engines during crawling so they don't rank the outgoing links. I think this is what the OP wants. So unless the robot runs all the JavaScript before inspection, it won't make a difference.

Comment: @Jonathon I see your point. I would however expect them to run the JavaScript, since not doing so would mean indexing something that's not real. But you might very well be right